# Auto Upgradable WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I'm working on application that does some tests on Windows Servers. Front end of application connects to small application installed on each server via WCF.

Problem with this flow is that when i make slight update to small application on server or even change WCF server signature i should re-install this application again on numerous servers.

How did you tackled such problem or would advice to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF handles most compatibility issues without complaining such as adding new parameters to a method (old clients still work, new parameters are initialized as default). Removing params also does not affect the client (extra params ignored). Other changes and how to deal with them can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx.

For deployment, as stated in another answer click-once is a quick way to have client machines auto-update, if you prefer more of a push model, you may be able to setup msdeploy to push a build out to the other machines (provided you have access to them).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

could you use a more restful service, this would give you a little more flexibility to change?

Could you use click once deployment, to automatically redeploy when the app changes (if it is an app)?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730203.aspx